# Где найти TurboС++ для win 7 64 ?

Tags: windows-7, ide, c++

Помогите, пожалуйста, найти версию для `Windows 7 64 бита`.

Comment: Гугль сегодня не работает?

Answer (score 1):

[TurboC++ for Windows 7 x64](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Coding-languages-Compilers/TurboCplusplus-for-Windows-7.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

Я, конечно, могу ошибаться, но Turbo C был без ++ и под Dos. Был просто С++, без Turbo, а вот TurboC++ - не помню.

Comment: Хорошо, а на него ссылка, есть для win7 64?

Comment: Нет такого. Ставьте виртуальную машину или эмулятор dosnox и уже оттуда запускайте turboc

Comment: да спасибо как раз с dosbox'ом разобрался

Comment: был и турбо ++ :)